# grunt postcss "not found"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gruntjs, postcss

New to Grunt, trying to get a Gruntfile running for a wordpress project. I've got a package.json and Gruntfile.js in my root directory. I want to add grunt-postcss, but when I followed the instructions, I keep getting "Warning: Task "grunt-postcss" not found." I've probably set up Grunt wrong, as no matter what I run, I get task not found. Here's my Gruntfile contents:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    postcss: {
      options: {
        map: true, // inline sourcemaps
        processors: [
          require('pixrem')(), // add fallbacks for rem units
          require('autoprefixer')({browsers: 'last 2 versions'}), // add vendor prefixes
          require('cssnano')() // minify the result
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        src: 'css/*.css'
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['grunt-postcss']);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed the grunt-postcss module.

npm install grunt-postcss --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['grunt-postcss']);
```

to

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['postcss']);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have postcss installed.
   `npm install grunt-postcss`
2. Execute the following command in your shell(make sure to be inside virtualenv if you are using one):

`export PATH="/PATH_TO_YOUR_NODE_MODULES_DIRECTORY/.bin:$PATH"`

What the above command does is, it update your PATH variable and tells it to also check the above directory while looking for a command.